# Perl strange behaviour on unpack of floating value

Tags: perl, floating-point, endianness

I have this snippet with a *strange result* (279.1... vs. 279.6...):

```
$ perl -e "print unpack('f>', pack ('f>', 279.117156982422));"
279.617156982422
```

While this one works

```
$ perl -e "print unpack('f>', pack ('f>', 279.117256982422));"
279.117248535156
```

And those ones as well

```
$ perl -e "print unpack('f<', pack ('f<', 279.117156982422));"
279.11715698242

$ perl -e "print unpack('f', pack ('f', 279.117156982422));"
279.117156982422
```

What's wrong? Is that a bug in unpacking of non-native endian floating point values?

Note Perl is version 5.14.2 under [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) on a PC.

Comment: Are the first two cases run with different versions of perl or different operating systems?

Comment: What's the result of `pack` in the first case (I mean, what are the bytecodes)?

Comment: Reproducible here with 5.14.2 (on Cygwin on Win7x64).  Curious. You may have found a bug.  Note that `print unpack('H8', pack ('f>', 279.117156982422))` to get at the bits returns `438b8eff`, which is the correct bit pattern according to [this site](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html)

Comment: However, NOT reproducible on 5.10.2 on RHEL 6.1

Comment: Reproduced on perl v5.14.2 on Linux too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried on different versions of Perl on Linux (but not V5.14.2) and Windows (Strawberry V5.16.2). Works on them...

Comment: @XuDing Anything special about your Linux? Is it a 32bit system?

Comment: @SlavenRezic Yes, 32bit Ubuntu 12.10, Linux version 3.5.0-26-generic (buildd@akateko) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)

Comment: @XuDing Can you try `cpan -t Acme::Study::SREZIC` and see if it fails on your system?

Comment: Reproduced on a Windows 8.1 system, see http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/5f5ba05e-3e82-11e3-94cf-57ac40c32a75

Comment: I got the correct result using [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl), Perl version 5.18.2 (compiled 2014-01-07).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a GCC problem.

cpan -t Acme::Study::SREZIC passes OK on my 32bit systems where the Perl binary is compiled with GCC 4.5.4 or 4.6.3 or 4.6.4 and does not pass on systems where the Perl binary is compiled with GCC 4.7.3 or 4.8.3

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug in Perl's unpacking. It has difficulty in handling floats in the binary form `xxxxyyFF` at least in a 32-bit platform, where `80 <= yy <= BF`. The packed result will become `xxxxzzFF`, where `zz = yy + 40` (all in hexadecimal). And this is *not* a problem of endianness, as you could see here:

```
$ perl -e "print unpack('H8', pack ('f', unpack('f', pack('H8', '000088ff'))));"; 
0000c8ff
```

Comment: I wrote a bug report on rt.perl.org: https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=120405